# Related objects in Freebase

Tags: freebase

In Freebase API, I want to fetch related objects to an object in Freebase. For example:

When I type in "Michael Jordan" (http://www.freebase.com/m/054c1) it should return "Chicago Bull's" (http://www.freebase.com/m/0jm74).

I went over https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-cookbook but couldn't come up with a filter operand.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which API you are using, but if you were to use the [Freebase Search API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-overview),  you would get the `mid` of the entity, then plug that back in to another search appropriate to that entity.  The code below (in Javascript w/ jQuery) limits the input possibilities to a field where Mr.Jordan is present, then plugs it into a property found on basketball players: former teams.

```
    $(function()
         {
            $("#myInput").suggest().bind("fb-select", function(e, data)
                 {
                var topic_service = 'https://wwwlgoogleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic';
                var params = {
                    'filter' : '(all type:/sports/sports_award_winner)'
                 };
                $.getJSON(topic_service + data.id + '?callback=?', params, function(topic)
                    {
                    var teams = data.property['/basketball/basketball_player/former_teams']['values'];
                    for ( var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++)
                        {
                        alert(teams[i]);
                        }
                    })
                })
            });
```

You could do this without limiting the search, for more general types, but then you would have to do a query for what properties were held by that entity and then use that as a filter to get the data you were after.

On the other hand...

If you don't know that Jordan plays basketball, or what the properties of a basketball player are, you could call for the id of the links, find the properties of those links, then query for those properties on those links:

```
{
    "mid": "/en/michael_jordan",
    "type": [{
        "id":null,
        "properties": [{
            "id":null,
            "links": [{
                "source": {
                    "id":  "/en/michael_jordan"
                },
                "target": {
                    "id": null,
                    "optional": true,
                },
                "optional": true,
                "target_value": null
            }],
            "master_property": {
                "optional": true,
                "links": [{
                    "source": {
                        "id": null
                    },
                    "target": {
                        "id": "/en/michael_jordan"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
```

--This [code](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//events/io/2011/static/presofiles/querying_freebase_getting_more_from_mql.pdf) is taken from the slide pack of an I/O talk given by [Jamie Taylor](https://www.freebase.com/m/01xrygg) in 2011.